# How to call the interface method in its own class?

Tags: c#, interface, methods

My MySqlConnection class implements `IDatabaseConnection` interface. In update method, I want to call `connect()` but it cannot find this method, How can I call it?

```
class MySqlConnection : IDatabaseConnection
{
    void IDatabaseConnection.connect()
    {
        ...
    }

    void IDatabaseConnection.update()
    {         
        connect(); // here
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the correlation between `IDatabaseConnection` and `IDatabase` ??

Comment: @abatishchev: I think should be `IDatabaseConnection` only?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apparently you're using explicit interface implementation, except your syntax is incorrect (you mustn't specify an access modifier on it).

To call the method, just cast `this` to `IDatabaseConnection`:

```
void IDatabase.update(){

    ((IDatabase)this).connect();
 ...
}
```

Comment: +1. The other alternative, of course, is to implement the interface implicitly, unless that is not desirable.

Comment: operator `as` works (slightly) faster then `cast`, doesn't it?

Comment: @abatishchev: the reason to pick between `as` and regular casts is not performance. It's their behavior. `as` will produce a `null` upon failure, whereas a regular cast will throw an exception.

Comment: @Martinho: `(null).connect();` will throw an exception too :)

Comment: @abatishchev: A pointless and unhelpful exception. The thing is, if the cast can fail sometimes, use `as` and check for null. If the cast cannot possibly fail, use a regular cast. If it cannot fail, but it does, then blow up, that's what exceptions are for, not control flow. Catching either a NullReferenceException or an InvalidCastException is wrong.

Answer (score 4):

You can use:

```
(this as IDatabase).connect();
```

The reason is that you are implementing this interface explicitly, so you can only call these methods after a conversion. Why do you implement it explicitly and make these methods `private`? It's more common that a connection class has `public` `connect` and `update` methods, I think.

Comment: This isn't a good way; an explicit cast is preferable here. `as` should be used when the cast might fail, and is normally followed with a `null`-test.

Comment: @Ani: good point, but it won't make a difference here, as the compiler won't care about the cast.

Comment: @Martinho Fernandes: This is about readability; as a reader of the code, I would be fooled into thinking that this cast *might* fail; and that there was a possible null-dereferencing issue here. The same goes for static code-analysis tools.

Comment: @Ani: Readability may be a factor. I personally don't care, but if others may find issue, regular casts are better. But smart code analysis tools know that because the class implements the interface and `this` is never null, it never fails. R# is smart enough, for example.

Answer (score 2):

Explicit interface implementation:

```
class MySqlConnection : IDatabaseConnection
{
    void IDatabaseConnection.connect()
    {
        //
    }

    void IDatabaseConnection.update()
    {
        (this as IDatabaseConnection).connect();
    }
}
```

---

**Rather better** - implicit interface implementation:

```
class MySqlConnection : IDatabaseConnection
{
    public void connect()
    {
        //
    }

    public void update()
    {
        connect();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would you say implicit implementation is better ? I would usually agree, but perhaps the OP has a good reason for using explicit implementation...

Comment: +1 Agree that an implicitly implementation is more reasonable in most circumstances.

Comment: @Thomas: I think that explicit implementation should take place only if you have inherited 2 interfaces with methods with the same name and their implementation should be different, e.g. `IFoo:Do()` and `IBar:Do()`

Answer (score 0):

That is called explicit interface implementation. But if you write your class like this it works normally:

```
class MySqlConnection : IDatabase
{
    public void connect()
    {
        ...
    }

    public void update()
    {         
        connect(); // here
        ...
    }
}
```

Notice that the methods are implemented as public methods.

Explicit implementation makes them inaccessible everywhere, even inside the class itself. That's why you can't use the `private` keyword when declaring them. They can still be accessed "publicly" through the interface, however. If for some good reason you really want to use explicit implementations you can cast to the interface and call from there:

```
((IDatabase)this).connect();
```

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a couple of problems here -- your MySqlConnection doesn't implement the IDatabase interface, but you're explicitly implementing a method in that interface?

This might help -- I may have misunderstood what you're trying to achieve.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288461(VS.71).aspx